# Сделать первую букву каждого слова заглавной

Tags: javascript

у меня выдает ошибку` [image: запятая после слова]

```js
document.getElementById("knopka").addEventListener('click', F);

function F(){
   t = document.getElementById("text").value;
   arjeq = t.toLowerCase().split(' ');
   for (var i = 0; i < arjeq.length; i++){
       arjeq[i] = arjeq[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arjeq[i].substring(1);
   } 
f = document.getElementById("elq");
f.innerHTML = arjeq;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text">
<button id="knopka">PRESS</button>
<h1 id="elq"></h1>
```

Comment: Никакой ошибки нету код работает!

Comment: А текст ошибки какой?

Comment: 'bob'.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + 'bob'.substring(1); ===> Bob - можно так.

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов зачем там запятая ставит ? это и есть ошибка

Comment: @Serhii не помог

Comment: потому что `arjeq` - массив https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Элемент для вывода результата
var elq = document.getElementById("elq");
// Инпут для ввода строки 
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var knopka = document.getElementById("knopka");


/* Функция получает строку,
 * отдает строку с заглавной буквой
 */
function capitalizeString(str) {
  /*
   * str.split('') - делит строку на буквы, на выходе массив
   * str.split('')[0] - первая буква
   * str.split('')[0].toUpperCase() - делаем заглавной
   * str.slice(1) - обрезаем строку, получаме строку без первой буквы
   * str.split('')[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1) - складываем
   * return str.split('')[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1) - возвращаем результат
   */
  return str.split('')[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
}

function F(){
  // Получаем значение из инпута
  var textValue = text.value;
  
  // Делим строку из инпута на слова, по пробелу. Получается массив из строк
  var words = textValue.split(' ');
  
  // Здесь будем хранить резултат, каждый раз писать в DOM не лучшая идея
  var result = '';
  // Проходим по массиву
  words.forEach(function(word){
    // При каждой итерации добавлем к результату слово с заглавной буквы через пробел
    result += ' ' + capitalizeString(word);
  });
  
  // выводим результат 
  elq.innerHTML = result;
}
knopka.addEventListener('click', F);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text">
<button id="knopka">PRESS</button>
<h1 id="elq"></h1>
```

**UPD**: Добавил комменты

Comment: Хорошо бы было добавить пояснений в ваш ответ.